# unable to get url as query string parameter in node express js

Tags: node.js, http, express, server

How do i take URL as query string parameter in node.js.

For eg : When i hit browser with the below url:

http://localhost:3000/key1/https://www.google.com/key2/c , I'm unable to get value1 as "https://www.google.com". I'm getting error in browser saying cannot get querystring. But my code works if I replace url with some random string or number.

Comment: What should i do in order to get https://www.google.com in arg1 or else I should be passing google.com in some other way in the local host url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because your url paramater is not url encoded. If you have slashes, or a variety of other symbols such as :, it will break your params.

For example,

```
param1 = thisisastring,
param2 = thisisalsoastring

<ip:port>/param1/param2
```

Okay!

```
param1 = thisisastring/somethingelse,
param2 = thisisalsoastring

<ip:port>/param1/param2
```

Broken!

Why?

express sees 3 parameters:

```
thisisastring somethingelse thisisalsoastring
```

Solution: [URL encode](https://www.urlencoder.org/) your requests. There are a ton of libraries to do this.

https://www.google.com should be encoded as: https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com

Notice no slashes or colons. ;)